# Convergence of differentiated power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> Consider $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$ and suppose that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(0)$ converges.
>
> Prove that $\forall z \in \mathbb C, \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(z)$ converges.

I'm pretty stumped on this one.

The convergence $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(0)$ indicates that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! a_n$ converges.

What then ?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: $f^{(n)}(0)= n!a_{n}$ so you should have the convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!a_{n},$ shouldn't you?

Comment: @Dario of course ;)

Comment: Is it really only (possibly) conditional convergence that is assumed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $R_n=\sum_{k\geq n} k! a_k$. We have $R_n\to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Let $N>0$. We have for $n\geq 0$

$$f^{(n)}(z)=\sum_{k\geq n} k! a_k \frac{z^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}=\sum_{l\geq 0} (n+l)! a_{n+l}\frac{z^l}{l!}$$ 
and hence
$$\sum_{n=0}^N f^{(n)}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^N (\sum_{l\geq 0} (n+l)! a_{n+l})\frac{z^l}{l!}$$

We have a finite number of series, so one can exchange the summations:

$$\sum_{n=0}^N f^{(n)}(z)=\sum_{l\geq 0}(\sum_{n=0}^N (n+l)! a_{n+l} ) \frac{z^l}{l!}=\sum_{l\geq 0} (R_l-R_{l+N+1})\frac{z^l}{l!}$$

Hence, if $g(z)=\sum_{l\geq 0}R_l\frac{z^l}{l!}$, we have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^N f^{(n)}(z)-g(z)=-\sum_{l\geq 0}R_{N+l+1}\frac{z^l}{l!}$$

Fix  $\varepsilon>0$. As $R_m$ goes to zero as $m\to \infty$, we can find  $M$ such that for all $n\geq M$, we have $|R_n|<\varepsilon$. This gives if $N\geq M$:

$$|-\sum_{l\geq 0}R_{N+l+1}\frac{z^l}{l!}|\leq \sum_{l\geq 0}\varepsilon\frac{|z|^l}{l!} =\varepsilon \exp(|z|)$$
and this finish the proof.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is more of a hint than an answer because it applies only if the convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}(0)$ is assumed to be absolute.

In that case, calculate
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{\left(n\right)}\left(z\right) & = & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=n}^{\infty}a_{\ell}\frac{\ell!}{\left(\ell-n\right)!}\cdot z^{\ell-n}\\
 & \overset{\left(\ast\right)}{=} & \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left[a_{\ell}\cdot\ell!\sum_{n=0}^{\ell}\frac{z^{\ell-n}}{\left(\ell-n\right)!}\right]\\
 & \overset{k=\ell-n}{=} & \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left[a_{\ell}\cdot\ell!\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}\right],
\end{eqnarray*}
where I used the absolute convergence of $\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}a_{\ell}\cdot\ell!$
to justify the interchange of summation in $\left(\ast\right)$ by
noting that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left[\left|a_{\ell}\cdot\ell!\right|\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\ell}\left|\frac{z^{\ell-n}}{\left(\ell-n\right)!}\right|\right]\\
 & = & \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left[\left|a_{\ell}\cdot\ell!\right|\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\left|\frac{z^{k}}{k!}\right|\right]\\
 & \leq & e^{\left|z\right|}\cdot\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left|a_{\ell}\cdot\ell!\right|<\infty
\end{eqnarray*}
This also shows that the final series exists.

EDIT: It might be worth noting that the final series also exists if the series
$\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}a_{\ell}\ell!$ is only assumed to converge
conditionally. To see this, note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left[a_{\ell}\ell!\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}\right] & = & e^{z}\cdot\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}a_{\ell}\ell!+\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left[a_{\ell}\ell!\cdot\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}\right)-e^{z}\right)\right]\\
 & = & e^{z}\cdot\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}a_{\ell}\ell!-\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left[a_{\ell}\ell!\cdot\sum_{k=\ell+1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}\right].\qquad\left(\square\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now note that $\left(a_{\ell}\cdot\ell!\right)_{\ell\in\mathbb{N}}$
is a null-sequence, hence bounded by some $C>0$. This implies
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\left[\left|a_{\ell}\ell!\right|\cdot\sum_{k=\ell+1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{z^{k}}{k!}\right|\right] & \leq & C\cdot\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=\ell+1}^{\infty}\frac{\left|z\right|^{k}}{k!}\\
 & = & C\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\left|z\right|^{k}}{k!}\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}1\right)\right]\\
 & = & C\cdot\left|z\right|\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left|z\right|^{k-1}}{\left(k-1\right)!}\\
 & = & C\cdot\left|z\right|\cdot e^{\left|z\right|}<\infty,
\end{eqnarray*}
so that the second series in $\left(\square\right)$ even converges
absolutely.

Comment: You're the third user who posts this answer ;)

Comment: Where are the others? O.o

Comment: They deleted theirs. Let me take a look at the edit.